# I am making a smart switch, I want to solve a problem where I need to read data and send data to cloud at the same time with esp32

Tags: multithreading, project, sensors, arduino-esp32

I am making a smart switch.
The switch has the following features :

1. The switch can be turned on or off through a physical switch or through thingspeak cloud switch.
2. it'll calculate the voltage, current and power using current and voltage sensor.

Now i have the code ready for both these functions, now the real problem is that sensors goes in a loop to calculate the value then upload on the cloud, but this causes a delay to the first function I can't use the switch neither the physical switch nor the cloud switch to turn the relay on or off.

I need a solution how to fix this so that I can calculate data and send and at the same time if I wanna use the relay I can get the values from cloud as well or the physical switch.

I am using an Esp32 microcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

Hi CHANAKYA SUNIL JHA,

This is easily doable with FreeRTOS implementation in your code. I assume you are doing this project in Arduino IDE.

With FreeRTOS, you can implement two tasks, and assign each task to each of the core of your ESP32 and allow it to run in parallel.

I will provide a sample code for pinning 2 separate LEDs to 2 separate cores of ESP32 below. You can use this for your project.

Link to code template: https://github.com/Makerdemy/Advanced-ESP32/blob/master/Section%203/3.4/Code/LED_Dual_Core/LED_Dual_Core.ino

I hope this will be helpful and you are able to finish the project

Happy Tinkering,
Thank You.
Naveen PS